# Uninstalled VisualSVN Client but Menu Context entries are still there

Tags: svn, contextmenu, visualsvn

how can I remove the entires on the Context Menu related to VisualSVN client ...after I deleted that software from my machine ?

Comment: Assuming he used the add remove program wizard and didn't just delete the folder.

Comment: @SteveRobillard ...I have to admit your comment made me laugh a bit.

Comment: @PreetSangha Yes I did reboot, i also look for entries on the registry and still getting those icons.

Comment: @Developer Honestly rebooting Windows was my first guess as well. :)

Comment: Recommending that this be moved to superuser.com.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Backup Your Registry

Make sure you set a system restore point first.

### Use the Registry Editor

You should be able to repair your context menu using the Registry Editor

```
HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\*\shellex\ContextMenuHandlers
HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Directory\shellex\contextmenuhandlers
```

### Sources

- http://www.howtogeek.com/howto/windows-vista/add-open-with-notepad-to-the-context-menu-for-all-files/
- http://www.addictivetips.com/windows-tips/remove-useless-items-from-right-click-context-menu-by-hacking-registry/

Answer (score 1):

There are lots of third-party tools that can customize your system context menu. Using these tools, you can add or remove items to your system context menu. As an example, take a look at [this link](http://www.softpedia.com/get/System/OS-Enhancements/Context-Menu-Editor.shtml).

Edit:

Go to this registry key for WinXP. All context menu extentions are located there.

```
HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\*\shellex\ContextMenuHandlers
```